# Android ActionBar class could not be found

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-support-library, android-support-design

I am trying to add an ActionBar to my main_activity however I receive the error
    `The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar`
I have both the support repository and the support library installed and want to know which dependencies I should add to fix this problem. The minimum SDK version is 15 and the target SDK version is 23 if that would help with the problem. I'm new to Android development so sorry if I sound stupid!

Comment: have you tried after restarting the IDE you are using?

Comment: Yep I have tried that to no success, was unsure whether I needed to use certain project dependencies to make it work?

Comment: The actionbar is deprecated, you should use Toolbar instead.

Comment: Ok thank you, is that available from within the theme tab in the activity_main design view or will I code that in XML instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

And in your xml layout file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
```